# Changing css styles dynamically based on current values

Tags: css

I was wondering, if there is a way to change css values based on current css values.

for example, if i want to change a value from 100 to 90 i have to do it like this:

```
.test{
    margin-top:100px;
}
.test:hover{
    margin-top:90px;
}
```

But is it possible to do something like this, and have the same effect?

```
.test{
    margin-top:100px;
}
.test:hover{
    margin-top:(-10px);
}
```

Thanks in advance, i hope i am making my question very clear.

BTW: I am NOT looking for a JavaScript solution, since I already know how to do that, I am simply wondering if it is possible with only CSS

Comment: When you say "dynamically" do you mean based on a value that isn't necessarily known ahead of time? Your example implies this is just for convenience, to avoid needing to update two separate values... But if you actually need to adjust this at run-time without knowing what the original value is in advance then this becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no, you cannot do this with CSS ***alone***, as it isn't a dynamic language.

When [**CSS variables**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) are supported/release, I would imagine you could do something similar to this.

Here is an example given:

> **[2.3 Resolving Dependency Cycles](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/#cycles)** - Example 8

```
<one><two><three /></two></one>
one   { var-foo: 10px; }
two   { var-bar: calc(var(foo) + 10px); }
three { var-foo: calc(var(bar) + 10px); }
```

In the meantime, I suggest looking into [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/).